# Getting and showing user info in joomla user events

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

My target is onUserAfterSave event where i will assign the new registered user to k2 group as joomla default registration don't do for k2.

But first want to test how do i get user info in joomla user events and see the info as i don't use any debugging for my plugin development.Starting with onUserLogin event, went this far -

```
function onUserLogin($user,$options)
{
 $user = JFactory::getUser();
 $name = $user['fullname'];
 $username = $user['username'];
 $email = $user['email'];
 echo $email; dump($email); //no output shows in local site by these lines
}
```

As i got above from [this url](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2456503) .
I searched through web and not much documentation on example of user events, that's very bad as joomla is getting very popular.so need solution all the ways...

Comment: What's your problem now?

Comment: @dasun what i wrote clearly